# How to let input appear in path without ?search in NODEjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

Hi I am doing a NodeJS practice and I would like to let the input appear on the url as (website).com/results/NameOfCountry, where NameOfCountry is a variable containing the input by the user.
I don't know how to do it after trying path.dirname(), which I don't think is correct.

Everytime I key in the country name, it would show a link ending like /results?searchCountry=America and I'd like to get rid of the ?searchCountry because the correct path has an ending like /results/America

Could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Here's the Code
**NodeJS:**

```
var express = require("express");
var haste = express();
var bp = require("body-parser");
var request = require("request");
 var mime=require('mime-types');

haste.set("view engine", "ejs");

haste.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.render("search");
})

haste.get("/results", function(req, res){
    var apple = "https://api.covid19api.com/total/country/" + query;
    var query = req.you.value;
    request(apple, function(error, response, require){
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
            var data = JSON.parse();
            res.render("info", {data:data});
        }
    })
})



haste.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server has started!");
});
```

On EJS, here's how the input form is:

```
<h1>
    Find Cases By Country:
</h1>
<form action="/results" method="GET">
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter country" class="you">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to route params, then it is something like

```
haste.get("/results/:NameOfCountry", function(req, res){ ....}
```

where route/path params are prepended with a `:`. Then you have access to `:NameOfCounty` to use as needed via `req.params`

Comment: I'd like my input to set the path instead of setting path directly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to use a custom path for each search result instead of queries. You can achieve this with *parameters* in express.

A basic get route would look like this:

```
app.get("/results/:search", function(req, res){
    var parameter = req.params.search;
    //send your custom response here
}
```

The parameter variable contains what is after */results/* as a string